# Specifying a pronunciation of a word in Microsoft Speech API

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm working on a small application in C# which performs speech recognition using Microsoft Speech API.

I need to add some non-english words to grammar, whose pronunciation don't obey english pronunciation rules.

Is it possible specify their pronunciation using International Phonetic Alphabet ?
If yes, which methods should be used ?

Answer (score 3):

The way to achieve custom pronunciation here is by passing an [SrgsDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.srgsgrammar.srgsdocument.aspx) to the [`Grammar` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554238.aspx).  This allows specification per http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/.

I have not done this and it looks non-trivial, but this ought to allow you to do what you want.